# accessing module-level functions in Python if their name is stored in a variable

Tags: python, module, eval

What is the best way to use a function at the top of a module if do not know the name of the object in advance: The function might depend on user input and hence its name is stored in a variable.

One solution uses [eval()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval): For example, in [ScipyCookbook/SignalSmooth: smooth()](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/SignalSmooth) (also referenced in an answer to [StackOverflow: Python Smooth Time Series Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515720/python-smooth-time-series-data))

```
import numpy  
window = 'hanning'
w = eval('numpy.'+window+'(11)')
```

will be equivalent to

```
w = numpy.hanning(11)
```

However, is there a better method than using fragile/potentially dangerous `eval`?

For instance, wouldn't using [vars()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars)

```
w = vars(numpy)[window](11)
```

be preferred? Any better/more pythonic ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a dictionary mapping the valid window function names to the actual functions:

```
windows = {"bartlett": numpy.bartlett,
           "blackman": numpy.blackman,
           "hamming": numpy.hamming,
           "hanning": numpy.hanning,
           "kaiser": numpy.kaiser}
```

If you use `eval()`, the user is basically allowed to execute arbitrary code.

The variant

```
w = vars(numpy)[window](11)
```

is definitely better than using `eval()`, but it still does not make sure the function the user selected makes sense in the given context.  (And usually, you'd use `getattr()` for this instead.)

Comment: I like this a whole lot better than any other approach such as eval or getattr. This is my personal method as well. +1. What I really like about this is how manageable it is to swap out the handlers at any point.

Comment: I would argue getattr is a better option here - it requires no repeating yourself. If there is a need to change handlers, the fine, but otherwise, unnecessary.

Comment: @Lattyware: The `numpy` module contains almost 500 callable objects.  Only five of them are useful as window functions.  Using `getattr()` will allow all 500 functions to be used, and most of them will lead to at least strange behaviour in your program.  Moreover, I don't consider this "repeating myself".  I'd consider this decoupling of the user interface of our program from the API of NumPy.  We map the *names* these window functions are supposed to have in the program to the *function objects* in NumPy -- there's no repetition.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Fair enough, in which case, in this situation, I'd agree that's the better option. I don't have much experience with numpy, so I was treating this as a general case. You make a good point.

Comment: I agree that a dispatch table is in general the safest approach and most appropriate for the numpy example. For other cases I'll keep `getattr()` in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A module's functions are attributes of the module, so you can do:

```
window = "hanning"
getattr(numpy, window)(11)
```

`vars()` is also fine.

Comment: Also, you can use getattr 3rd parameter for passing a fallback function.