# Interpolate in one direction

Tags: matplotlib

I have sampled data and plot it with `imshow()`:

[image]

I would like to interpolate just in horizontal axis so that I can easier distinguish samples and spot features.
Is it possible to make interpolation just in one direction with MPL?

---

**Update**:
SciPy has whole package with various interpolation methods.
I used simplest interp1d, as suggested by *tcaswell*:

```
def smooth_inter_fun(r):
    s = interpolate.interp1d(arange(len(r)), r)
    xnew = arange(0, len(r)-1, .1)
    return s(xnew)

new_data = np.vstack([smooth_inter_fun(r) for r in data])
```

Linear and cubic results:

[image]

[image]

As expected :)

Comment: The answer to the question is technically, yes. What kind of interpolation are you interested in? What characteristics of the interpolation make you expect it to more easily distinguish features?

Comment: Any kind of interpolation across X-axis will make each of 22 samples more distinguished at least because: 1. horizontal borders will make samples more "individual" and 2. interpolating horizontally will make feature more easy to spot because vertical border will disappear, 3. it would provide new view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) covers a range of interpolation available in numpy/scipy.  If you want to just one direction, I would work on each row independently and then re-assemble the results.  You might also be interested is simply smoothing your data ([exmple](http://argandgahandapandpa.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/python-numpy-moving-average-for-data/), [Python Smooth Time Series Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515720/python-smooth-time-series-data), [Using strides for an efficient moving average filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter)).

```
def smooth_inter_fun(r):
    #what ever process you want to use
new_data = np.vstack([smooth_inter_fun(r) for r in data])
```

Comment: `new_data = np.vstack([smooth_inter_fun(r) for r in data])` so simple. thanks.